# "Есть два мотива" означает, что есть ТОЛЬКО ДВА мотива?

Tags: смысл, лексическая-сочетаемость

Спор с сыном. Помогите разобраться. Предметом спора стала  моя фраза "Есть два мотива для участия в митинге: желание высказаться и желание стать примером".

Считаю, что словосочетание "есть два мотива" делает список мотивов конечным. Я понимаю это как "есть только два мотива". Сын считает, что если слова, указывающие на конечность списка, отсутствуют, то он (список) открыт, просто сейчас речь идет именно о двух мотивах.

Я считаю, что, если участник обсуждения не сделал уточнения о том, что не он автор высказывания, значит, автором является сам участник. То есть в разговоре с сыном я не стала говорить, что это именно мое мнение, так как я считаю, что это и так понятно.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы хотите передать определенный смысл, то предметом спора являестя построение фразы. А если вы обсуждаете смысл уже готовой фразы, то предметом спора являетя смысл.

Comment: Мы обсуждаем смысл готовой фразы.

Comment: Ирина, если Вы автор, то в Вашей власти изменить фразу так, чтобы она максимально четко передавала Вашу мысль и не вызывала споров. Такой стиль предпочтительней.

Comment: Дело не в изменении фразы. Я считаю, что так как я ее построила полностью соответствует тому смыслу, который я хотела донести.

Comment: Как следует из развернувшейся дискуссии, мало кто из нас понял в точности, что Вы хотели донести, то есть что именно для ВАС есть два мотива для участия именно в ЭТОМ митинге.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

**Есть два мотива для участия в митинге: желание высказаться и желание стать примером.**

Чтобы определиться со смыслом этого высказывания, **нужен контекст**. Если же рассматривать одно предложение, то в нем есть **семантическая незаконченность (семантическая некорректность)**

Разумеется, логично предположить, что мотивов может быть много, но **обсуждаются два мотива**. Соответственно, предложение должно выглядеть примерно так:

**У них** есть два мотива для участия в митинге: желание высказаться и желание стать примером.

Или: **Можно назвать** два мотива для участия в митинге: желание высказаться и желание стать примером.

То есть мы должны обозначить область применения для глаголов "есть, существует", в противном случае обсуждение не имеет смысла.

**ВЫВОД**

**"Мы обсуждаем смысл готовой фразы"**

Но эта фраза является семантически неполной, поэтому **она не имеет единственного  смысла**. Можно сравнить с уравнением, которое имеет **два решения**, а мы хотим доказать, что верно только одно из них.

Comment: Боже мой, какая незаконченность?! Ординарная, ничем не примечательная фраза, а сколько философии вокруг...

Comment: Если фраза ординарная, то почему участники форума дают разные ответы?

Comment: Ну, вообще-то можно делать глубокомысленные заключения даже из созерцания яичной скорлупы. Может быть, им нравится. Но заметьте, самые грамотные участники -- Людмила, Слава1947 и еще пара человек -- молчат.

Comment: Как бы так невзначай зерна от плевел отделил)

Comment: @Niemand  А Вы обратитесь на сайт Русский язык Мета с предложением. Пусть они присваивают участникам форума звания и знаки отличия, например: самые грамотные (Людмила, Слава1947 и еще пара человек (надо бы их тоже обозначить для ясности), потом второй эшелон, ну а дальше все остальные. И чтоб отвечали на вопросы в таком же порядке. А может быть,  лучше наоборот, самых грамотных на потом оставить? Надо Вам еще с модераторами посоветоваться.

Comment: Не надо званий, отличить и без того нетрудно.

Comment: Нетрудно - это значит легко (при слитном написании НЕ). Опять же легко Вам, а не другим. Может быть, Вы поделитесь с Обществом Вашей методикой, если уж Вы начали озвучивать ее результаты.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, спор не о том, как построить фразу, а о том, как понять прочитанную фразу
"Есть два мотива для участия в митинге: желание высказаться и желание стать примером".

Когда утверждают, что есть определенное количество чего-либо, то имеют в виду, что этим список исчерпан. У меня есть два сына. В доме есть две комнаты.

Выяснив, что смысл фразы не соответствует истине, переходим к построению корректной фразы. Эта задача решается в контексте. Как вариант, я бы написал как-то так: "Поговорим о двух мотивах для участия в митинге: о желании высказаться и желании стать примером". Или так: "Среди мотивов для участия в митинге есть два, привлекшие наше внимание: желание высказаться и желание стать примером".

Comment: Спор о смысле фразы, которая звучит (написана) определенным образом. Мы ничего не переделываем. Вопрос не о переделке фразы. Чей смысл фразы ,по-вашему, не соответствует истине? Мой или сына?. И что такое истина в контексте нашей беседы? Мне Ваш ответ не понятен.

Comment: Ирина! О смысле фразы. Все мы все согласились, что смысл Вашей фразы в том, что есть два и только два мотива для участия в митинге. Но это не все. При этом смысл фразы также в том, что это утверждение о двух мотивах имеет общий характер, то есть речь не идет о мотивах отдельного человека. Далее. Хотя слово "митинг" употреблено в единственном числе, смысл фразы в отрыве от контекста состоит в том, что речь идет об участии в  митингах вообще.

Comment: Теперь об истине. Истина состоит в том, что список мотивов, побуждающих людей участвовать в митингах, не ограничен двумя названными Вами. Поэтому смысл Вашей фразы не соответствует истине.

Answer (score 1):

Тут два аспекта:

1. Мотивы определяют поведение, посещение же конкретного митинга - это не поведение, а поступок. У поступка есть причины, мотивы же его как правило располагаются в иррациональной плоскости и плохо поддаются не то что подсчёту, но даже выявлению. "Все пошли и я пошёл", - вполне себе мотив, но автор высказывания явно имеет в в виду именно причины.
2. "Два мотива" или "две причины" означает конечный список. Из фразы нельзя понять насколько верна здесь такая категоричность, если из контекста ясно, что мнение субъективно такая фраза вполне корректна. Если же текст претендует на объективность, то лучше добавить слово "основные", "Есть две основные причины". С мотивами сложнее, так как какой основной, а какой второстепенный даже сам человек зачастую не знает, но можно использовать "наиболее частых".

Comment: По-Вашему, есть мотивы поведения, но  нет смысла в сочетании "мотивы поступка"?

Comment: Я являюсь автором обсуждаемой фразы и это именно я считаю, что именно для меня существует только 2 мотива участия в митинге. Разве беседуя люди делают акцент на том, что высказываемое сейчас мнение принадлежит им? Я,например, уточняю источник высказывания только в случае, когда им не являюсь я сама.

Comment: Ирина, это важное дополнение к вопросу. Поместите его туда (в вопрос).

Comment: Ирина, скорее всего, Вы говорите не о посещении конкретного митинга, а об участии в митингах вообще.  И о мотивах такого поведения. Я прав?

Comment: Речь о конкретном митинге.

Comment: Интересное дело, так это и есть "контекст", которого мы не знаем, а вы знаете.  Фактически получается: У МЕНЯ есть два мотива для участия в ЭТОМ митинге: желание высказаться и желание стать примером. Тогда, разумеется, ряд закрытый, ситуация вполне конкретная. Автор назвал все мотивы, которые у него ЕСТЬ,

Comment: Перед фразой мог быть и такой контекст.  "Зачем люди ходят ходят на митинге. Я думаю так. Есть два мотива для участия в митинге: желание высказаться и желание стать примером". Тогда это будет мнение вообще и мнение о других, а фраза может быть открытой.

Comment: @Jasmin Именно этот "контекст" я и просил Ирину добавить к вопросу, а не рассуждения о том, кто автор фразы.

Comment: Совершенно верно, но кажется автор вопроса с этим не согласен. Он считает, что мы не поняли то, что и так понятно. Вот так неточное описание ситуации ведет к отсутствию положительного результата и ненужной потери времени для всех.

Comment: Описание ситуации точное, добавить к описанию нечего. И Вы на самом деле не поняли то, что и так понятно. До сих пор не поняли.  Печально.

Comment: @JИрина Главкова,   я думаю, что печалится никому не надо, а Вам-то особенно. Наш сайт вопросов и ответов не единственный, и, возможно, в другом месте Вас  поймут правильно.

Comment: Печально,  @Jasmin, печально, что мы с Вами такие непонятливые, не дотягиваем до уровня наиболее продвинутых авторов вопросов. Если автору понятно, то должно быть и читателю понятно, а если читателю непонятно, то это его проблема. Не так ли?

Comment: Да уж, авторы вопросов нас часто удивляют, и каждый в своем роде.

Comment: @МаркИз а что вы понимаете под словом "аспект"? Вернее - так. Два аспекта - Это взаимоисключающее сущности или сосуществующие в одном и том же понимании? Весь дальнейший разговор под вашим ответом зашел в тупик, как я понимаю, именно из-за этой неоднозначности

Comment: @М_Г *Если автору понятно, то должно быть и читателю понятно* а вот это не обязательно. Иногда интересный вопрос начинается именно с подобного недоразумения. При этом совершенно не важно, что автор не тот вопрос хотел задать, как его поняли.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь уместно вспомнить общеизвестный анекдот "И ты тоже прав!"

*Я одно могу добавить к эти словам ребе. В таких вопросах всегда правы и неправы обе стороны. Никакими нормами русского языка (а мы здесь, собственно, отвечаем только за них: нормы и язык в целом) не устанавливается право на эксклюзивное понимание того, что прямо не вытекает из правил. 
Существуют лишь одна обязательная истина - та, что устанавливается лингвистической экспертизой, но и она ограничена в применении юридической сферой. Все остальное - мнения, которые не могут сами по себе основаниями для аргументации быть не могут.*

Что лично я вижу во фразе. С формальной точки зрения она не полна. Для кого "существует"? При каких условиях? В какой момент? Ну, положим, это все можно понять из контекста. Но самое-то главное: а с каких позиций оценивать сказанное?

Математик однозначно станет на сторону вашего сына. Для него утверждение "существует два" означает "существует **как минимум** два" - то есть два, три и так далее до бесконечности.

Филолог скорее всего усомнится в такой формулировке... Для него такая фраза будет означать, "**я знаю** два мотива". И это в общем-то тоже не в вашу пользу.

Но ваш текст явно не предназначен для чтения специалистами. Так вот на бытовом уровне такой вопрос просто не встанет, кто там прав - и что хотел сказать автор. Сказано два - значит два. А про три ничего не сказано. И про одну тоже. Это свойство бытового мышления, если не напрягаться, то и никаких вопросов не возникает.

Вот я вам на примере своего авторства объясню, как мыслит человек в быту.
**Джон получает 200 фунтов в неделю.**
**Верно ли, что Джон получает 300 фунтов в неделю**? Нет. Он получает 200.
**Верно ли, что Джон получает 100 фунтов в неделю**? Нет. Он получает 200.
Спросите об этом сына, если парень неглупый, задумается. Вы рассуждаете примерно так же, как мой условный обыватель, что не запрещено.

Но это, разумеется, не повод, чтобы признать вашу фразу корректной во всех отношениях. Вы не можете полагаться на то, что среди всех читателей не найдется братьев по разуму вашего сына. Для них надо уточнить. В зависимости от смысла:
Существует **ровно** два мотива.
Существует **как минимум** два мотива.
Существует **не более чем** два мотива.
Это основные варианты, а так можно еще много придумать формулировок - русский язык ими богат.

Мораль. Смотрите по контексту. Если вас могут в конкретном контексте понять неправильно (как ваш сын), то фразу надо уточнить. Невозможно доказать каждому, что он неправ. Пишите так, чтобы сомнений не было.

Я посмотрел другие ответы, но не стал бы их комментировать. Там есть здравые рассуждения, но они, на мой взгляд, как бы в стороне от сути вопроса.
(+)
Что же касается вашего вопроса

> Разве беседуя люди делают акцент на том, что высказываемое сейчас
>   мнение принадлежит им? Я,например, уточняю источник высказывания
>   только в случае, когда им не являюсь я сама.

то это в корне неверная постановка. Речь не о том, кто автор высказывания. Да, это понятно, что оно принадлежит вам - и только вам. Но совершенно непонятно другое. Мотивы-то кому принадлежат?! Я понял, что вы делаете некое обобщение/наблюдение над среднестатистическими посетителями митингов. Без контекста иное представить трудно. Но этот момент вообще не обозначен в вопросе, так что его я вынес за скобки. Я отвечаю на вопрос тот, который задан, а не на тот, который автор хотел задать.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза понимается вполне однозначно, если не "влезать под кожу". Это вообще вредно – влезать под кожу. Это необходимо уметь разве что юристам да математикам, а у нас вполне обычная фраза. Ваш сын не прав.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш сын прав. Человек, утверждающий, что есть два мотива, приписываемые им неопределённым лицам, выбирает их из числа возможных как выгодные для подтверждения какого-то своего аргумента. Если он хочет заявить, что других не существует, или не может припомнить других мотивов, то он может добавить слово "только". В противном случае его собеседник волен рассматривать названные мотивы как примеры, приведённые в качестве наиболее существенных. К истине же предполагаемые мотивы других людей вообще не имеют отношения.